# Glassfish installation error: cannot open display

Tags: ssh, installation, java, shell, glassfish

When trying to extract the Glassfish jar file with

```
java -Xmx256m -jar glassfish-installer-v2.1-b60e-linux.jar
```

i get following error:

```
(.:31766): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

and extraction doesn't happen. It somehow assumes i'm on an real machine rather on a SSH shell. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append -console to the command:

```
java -Xmx256m -jar glassfish-installer-v2.1-b60e-linux.jar -console
```

Comment: THANKS (big thanks) - that did the trick. Why is java assuming i'm on an X11 machine?

Comment: Java isn't assuming, but the glassfish installer is assuming that. Can I pimp for an upvote?  ;)

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation (click on this box to dismiss)" sorry bro

Comment: nope, doesnt give me any points

Answer (score 1):

Can you use an ssh tunnel?

```
ssh -X my.host
```

You may also need to enable ssh forwarding in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Another option might be just do `unset DISPLAY` and see if that works.

Comment: neither of this options worked for me.